# Rewrite index when php is aready removed

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a code in my htaccess that removes the .php from every page on my site. The following code is as far as i came, but what i actually want is that every page has an slash after the name (still without php)
and that de index(.php) name is completely removed.

Icouldn't find something on the internet having these two combined. I did find a code that created a slash at the end but that created many problems with internally redirecting.

Is all of this possible and if so, how?

Many thanks in advance,

Paul

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: It does remove the .php and adds a /, but when i go from my index to antoher page (link in menu), for example settings this happens: --mydomain.com//index/settings/--

Comment: @Paul include a `<base href="/" />` at the top of your pages or make all your links absolute