# How link in php when a \ is added with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a previous question answered on how to add a / to my url and redirecting it internally.  The answer I got worked great, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145972/rewrite-index-when-php-is-aready-removed) but i've stumbled on a new problem.

When you recover your password you are forced to change it:

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
    if ($current_file !== 'changepassword.php' && $user_data['password_recover'] == 1) {
        header('Location: changepassword.php?force');
        exit();
    }
}
```

When you're on the index page, and are forced to change your password, the URL goes from mysite.com//index/ to mysite.com//index/changepassword/?force which obviously does not exist.

When I use ?force without changepassword.php it gets a "this page has an this page has redirect loop" warning, although it did work for other things like ?success.

Base href="/"  also doesn't have any effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess of your problem is that you replace a "terminating" `.php` with `/`. So `/index.php` turns into `/index/`. If you now redirect to `changepassword.php?force`, you will end up with `/index/changepassword/?force`.

But as the script `changepassword.php` likely is located at the same level as `index.php`, you have to use a host relative redirection, instead of a path relative redirection:

```
header('Location: /changepassword.php?force');
```

Please note the leading `/` in the location target.

Comment: So easy and yet i didn't manage to find it. Thank you very much